# Is End of Month (Eom) Rule overrides convention rule in Quantlib Schedule?

Tags: programming, finance, quantlib

```
import QuantLib as ql


startdate = ql.Date(31,1,2020)
maturityDate = ql.Date(31,1,2021)
calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Monthly)

calendar.addHoliday(ql.Date(31,3,2020))

aschedule =ql.Schedule(startdate,maturityDate,tenor,calendar,ql.Following,ql.Unadjusted,ql.DateGeneration.Forward,True)

list(aschedule)
```

**Output**
[Date(31,1,2020),
Date(29,2,2020),
Date(30,3,2020),
Date(30,4,2020),
Date(31,5,2020),
Date(30,6,2020),
Date(31,7,2020),
Date(31,8,2020),
Date(30,9,2020),
Date(31,10,2020),
Date(30,11,2020),
Date(31,12,2020),
Date(31,1,2021)]

> First I have added holiday on 31/03/2020 then I have passed ql.following to businessconvention but the date is shifted to 30/03/2020 instead of 01/04/2020.
> Is it overriding convention with EOM Rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.  If you tell the function that you want end-of-month dates, that's what it will return.  In that case, the Following convention is ignored.