# Is End of Month (Eom) Rule overrides Unadjusted convention rule in Quantlib?

Tags: programming, finance, quantlib

Concerning the post [Is End of Month (Eom) Rule overrides convention rule in Quantlib Schedule?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/73827/is-end-of-month-eom-rule-overrides-convention-rule-in-quantlib-schedule) I noticed that with Unadjusted convention has the same behavior. Is this wanted?

For example, with Target Calendar I want to advance 1 month with end of month rule True and Business Day convention Unadjusted from 31 May 2024. The date is shifted to 28 June 2024, instead of 30 June 2024, but in this case I did not ask that the arrival date is a working day.

Comment: Can you pls add some details to your question so that it can still be understood clearly and answered even if the Q&A at the link you have included is deleted or changed for some reason?

Comment: EOM Rule overrides Business Day convention Following by returning last working day of the month when the last day of the month is a holiday rather than the first working day after the last day of the month. I agree with this behavior since I asked end-of-months dates, but with Business Day convention unadjusted I think that it should returns last day of the month regardless it is a working day or not.

Answer (score 2):

That wasn't wanted.  It was fixed recently in https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/pull/1917, which will be included in the 1.34 release out in April 2024.